# Problem with ref (enumitem)

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem

I have a problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\quadre}[1]{\bigl[#1\bigr]}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Riferimenti bibliografici e sitografici}

\textbf{Bibliografia}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.25cm]
\item[$\quadre{\text{Man}}$] \label{Manetti}
Marco Manetti, Topologia, Springer--Verlag Italia, Milano 2008, pp. 139, 156.
\item[$\quadre{\text{Mun}}$] \label{Munkres}
James Munkres, Topology, 2\ap{nd} Ed., Pearson Education Limited, 2014, Chapter 4.
\end{enumerate}

\noindent\textbf{Sitografia}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.25cm]
\item[$\quadre{\text{Fie}}$] \label{UMT}
Zbigniew Fiedorowicz, \href{https://people.math.osu.edu/fiedorowicz.1/math655/UrysohnFrame.html}{The Urysohn Metrisation Theorem}.
\item[$\quadre{\text{Wiki1}}$] \label{HSA}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_separation_axioms}{History of the Separation Axioms}.
\item[$\quadre{\text{Wiki2}}$] \label{Normal space}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space}{Normal space}.
\item[$\quadre{\text{Wiki3}}$] \label{0-set}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function#Zero_set}{Zero set}.
\end{enumerate}

\noindent WRONG Refs: \ref{Manetti}, \ref{Munkres}, \ref{UMT}, \ref{HSA}, \ref{Normal space}, \ref{0-set}.\\
Correct Refs: \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Man}}$}, \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Mun}}$}, \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Fie}}$}, \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Wiki1}}$}, \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Wiki2}}$}, \textcolor{red}{$\quadre{\text{Wiki3}}$}.

\end{document}
```

I would like to obtain the Correct Refs without rewrite them, but only using the `\ref`-command of latex. Is it possible? Thank you so much!
(P.S.: I hope my question is clear. I already visited these sites: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128605/enumitem-referencing-items-in-enumerate?rq=1) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376938/personalized-enumerate-working-with-label-and-ref?rq=1))

Comment: When you specify the item label, `\refstepcounter` is not used and therefore `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentHref` are not set.

Comment: I don't understand. Unfortunately I'm new in enumitem and this is the fist time that I use the cross-references of enumitem.

Comment: `\item[$\quadre{\text{Man}}$] ` disables all reference features. You'll need to add some manual magick in order to be able to refence an item like this.

Comment: Why are you generating the bibliography like this? and not using the `thebibliography` env which allows you to use proper `\cite`?

Comment: Using `thebibliography` should be covered in any decent introduction to LaTeX

Comment: Never used thebibliography, ... I'll try to use it. Thank you

Comment: Using `thebibliography` and `\bibitem` would be a step in the right direction, but consider looking into using either biblatex or bibtex to generate your bibliography for you. I couldn't go back to manually writing out my references …